# xml file from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need your help to resolve an encoding issue as it seems.

I have a lot of input files that have the same pattern has this below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
  <root>
    <Module name="ModuleName">
      <Parameter Value="Data01$|Data02F1F5$|Data03:$|Data04 : $|"/>
    </Module>
  </root>
```

I need to be able to parse the file but there is a lot of special characters you can see below :

[image]

I can't use lxml or beautiful soup.

I tried the different options below but I couldn't find the solution :

```
from  xml.etree import ElementTree

file = 'StackOverflow.xml'

with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'iso-8859-1') as f:
    string = f.read()
    print(string)
with open(file, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(string)
    
with open(file, 'rb') as f :
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(f.read())

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration = True)

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding = "iso-8859-1")
    root = etree.parse(f, parser)
      
string = etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration = True, encoding="utf-8").decode('utf-8').encode('iso-8859-1')

with open('file', 'wb') as f:
    target.write(string)
```

Comment: The `encoding` attribute of the XML meta-tag is not there for decoration. It actually informs the parser how to interpret the bytes that follow. `ElementTree.parse(file)` should do the right thing. If not, edit your question with the error you get and a full hex dump of an example file. Your editor might be lying to you.

Comment: "I need to be able to parse the file but there is a lot of special characters you can see below" - **why should this cause a problem**? What exactly do you mean by "parse"  the file - that is, specifically what sort of result do you need to be able to get? "I tried the different options below but I couldn't find the solution :" - **What happens** when you try this code, and **how is that different** from what you expect? Please read [ask] and [mre], and make sure to describe a problem clearly.

Comment: `echo -e "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>\n<root value='Data01&#xD;&#xA; \xFF' />" > test.xml; python3 -c 'from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET; ET.dump(ET.parse("test.xml"))'` roundtrips the 0xFF character correctly as (UTF-8-encoded) `ÿ`.

Comment: @Botje It's not `\xFF` but `␌` (U+000C,  *Form Feed (FF)*)…

Comment: Hah. That makes more sense! Well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file_path = "StackOverFlow.xml"

tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

Output:

```
root {}
Module {'name': 'ModuleName'}
Parameter {'Value': 'Data01$|Data02F1F5$|Data03:$|Data04 : $|'}
```

Your picture said utf-8:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#even with utf-8 it works:
xml_str = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <Module name="ModuleName">
    <Parameter Value="Data01$|Data02F1F5$|Data03:$|Data04 : $|" />
  </Module>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

Output works also:

```
root {}
Module {'name': 'ModuleName'}
Parameter {'Value': 'Data01$|Data02F1F5$|Data03:$|Data04 : $|'}
```